# is approved and need to be approved

Tags: past-perfect

I would like to make sure about the meaning and difference about two important sentences:

- Permission to have a business trip is approved by the department head.
- Permission to have  a business trip must be approved by the department head.

I have talked with some colleagues  and they said they are the same. I was so confused. As I understand the first one means that the approval has been already given by the department head, while the second one means that we must have the approval from the department head. Am I correct? or not?

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is ambiguous, depending on context:

- If I'd I asked if the trip was approved, this could be a reply meaning, "Yes, the trip is approved by the department head."
- If it were in employee information, it could mean that in normal circumstances, the employee should seek approval from a department if a business trip is planned (though it doesn't preclude alternate paths).

The second sentence states clearly that approval from a department head is *required*.